# Warning from Excel file generated with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I have a PHP script that generates an Excel file from MySQL Database, however, the file gives me a warning when opened:

> The file format and extension of 'excel_2016-09-04-4.xls' don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?

When I open it anyway, the file has nothing wrong and the data is correct.

I can't seem to find out the problem with my PHP code since the Excel file data is correct.

Is it because of any errors in the `header`s or is there any other problem?

### PHP Code

```
<?php

// DB Connection

$filename = 'excel_'.date('Y-m-d');

$sql = "SELECT * from table";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
$file_ending = "xls";

ob_clean();
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");

//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
}

print("\n");    
//end of printing column names  
//start while loop to get data
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $schema_insert = "";
        for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
        {
            if(!isset($row[$j]))
                $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
            elseif ($row[$j] != "")
                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
            else
                $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
        }
        $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert .= "\t";
        print(trim($schema_insert));
        print "\n";
    }   
?>
```

**Note**: I am aware that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, but this's a test script, will convert to `mysqli_*` later.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can cause trouble.

Comment: Also if you have `\n\r` in your file you have some very, very strange files. `/\r?\n/` should be fine. `\r` only is legacy MacOS files.

Comment: @tadman Thanks, I'm not learning MySQL, and I will convert all of them to MySQLi soon

Comment: PDO is arguably the better of the two options, it has a number of benefits, one of which is it's not MySQL specific. `mysqli` is only marginally improved.

Comment: @tadman Noted, thanks! But do you have any idea what caused the warning?

Comment: Have you tried different MIME types? Do you know of a site that sends `.xls` files that don't generate this warning? I also don't see anything in your code that actually generates a valid XLS file.

Comment: CSV files **aren't** Excel files.

Comment: @mario So can I save it as .csv file instead?

Comment: What happens when you change the extension to csv? Excel might not like the xls ext.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It doesn't give the warning, however, the data isn't separated into columns

Comment: @luweiqi I tested your code by using mysqli_ functions (my system doesn't support the mysql_ API) and it worked correctly. It created the file with the tab-separated values. I would look into using PHPExcel https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ which is an option.

Comment: @luweiqi However, I did save it as `.xls` and opened it with Open Office. Wthen the dialog box came up, there were options to choose from, being "Separator options" (Tab, comma, semi-colon, etc.). Choosing "tab" opened the file correctly with each in their own cells. That is another option you could look into. Excel itself probably has that same dialog box popup. You can try saving it as an Excel file from there.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yup, the file data shows correctly, after I choose the correct option. Thanks for trying out! :)

Comment: @luweiqi You're welcome.